# suggestion on filtering lists items that corresponds to other lists

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I have four lists that are about 200,000 in length. The first list hold hour values between 1 and 24, here is an example

```
Hour_list = [1,2,2,2,5,5,7,5,12,18,24,.....] 
avg_occupancy = [0,5,9,5,13,24,56,23,.....]
avg_absences = [0,4,5,7,8,6,8,3,2,1.....]
Room_config= ['config_a001', 'configa002', 'configa003', 'configa004', 'configa005'.........]
```

I need to create 24 lists for each hour, list_hour1, List_Hour2 and so on and then filter the other three lists based on them, for example, List_Hour2 should contain the number 2, and avg_ocupancy_hour_2 should have all the items with indices that correspond to indices of the number 2 from the first list, this means that  avg_ocupancy_hour_2 = [5,9,5,......], avg_absences_2 = [4,5,7,....], Room_config= ['configa002', 'configa003', 'configa004', 'configa005'.........]

I think Zip would be good but not sure on how to utilize it for this situation

Comment: The lists are all (exactly) the same length, correct?

Comment: Are the lists all the same length? Does element N in each list correspond to the same measurement of whatever?

Comment: @jedwards, correct, lists are the same length

Comment: @CJ59 yes, lists are the same length and the N element corresoponds to all measures accross all four lists.

Comment: Why do you need these lists? You tagged `pandas` so depending upon what you intend to do the lists might be completely unecessary, as you could just `.groupby('Hour_list')` to aggregate everything for each hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah this is like.. exactly why data frames are a thing.

```
Hour_list = [1,2,2,2]
avg_occupancy = [0,5,9,5]
avg_absences = [0,4,5,7]
Room_config= ['config_a001', 'configa002', 'configa003', 'configa004']
```

Put em in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(dict(Hour_list = Hour_list, avg_occupancy = avg_occupancy, avg_absences = avg_absences, Room_config = Room_config))
```

Group em up:

```
hour_groups = data.groupby('Hour_list')
```

And now you can do whatever - you could calculate summary stats, or just iterate through all the hours:

```
for hour, hour_data in hour_groups:
    do_stuff(hour_data)
```

For your follow-up question, you could take the means and count as follows:

```
mean_data = hour_groups[['avg_occupancy', 'avg_absences']].agg('mean')
mean_data['count'] = hour_groups['avg_occupancy'].count()
```

Then you could just select whichever row has an index of 9 (so hour 9) with `.loc` and a logical test.

```
mean_data.loc[mean_data.index == 9, :]
```

The `, :` part tells pandas to return all columns of any rows that meet the `mean_data.index == 9` test.

Comment: SUPER! quick question, how do I access numbers from the lists by hour, for example, I need to know the avg absence and avg occupancy at hour 9. Could you show me a  quick example? I'm totally a newbie with Pandas, I have no idea what the data structure look like when they are grouped by Panda

Comment: Edited the answer to cover that.

Answer (score 2):

i porposed to you the following code; it is based on random data and use pandas library, also it will give you more flexibility:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

hours = np.arange(1, 25)
data = {'hours': [hours[np.random.randint(low=0, high=24)] for i in np.arange(1000)],
        'occupancy': np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=1000),
        'absences' : np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size= 1000)
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# Extract data for hour == 7
df[df['hours'] == 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` and `defaultdict` (and a class for cleanliness):

from collections import defaultdict

```
hour_list     = [1,2,2,2,5,5,7,5] 
avg_occupancy = [0,5,9,5,13,24,56,23]
avg_absences  = [0,4,5,7,8,6,8,3]
room_config   = ['configa001', 'configa002', 'configa003', 'configa004', 
                 'configa005', 'configa006', 'configa007', 'configa008']


class Tracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.avg_occupancy = defaultdict(list)
        self.avg_absences  = defaultdict(list) 
        self.room_config   = defaultdict(list)

    def add(self, h, ao, aa, rc):
        self.avg_occupancy[h].append(ao)
        self.avg_absences[h].append(aa)
        self.room_config[h].append(rc)

    # Optional, of course
    def __repr__(self):
        import json
        return json.dumps(vars(self), indent=4)


t = Tracker()
for row in zip(hour_list, avg_occupancy, avg_absences, room_config):
    t.add(*row)


print(t)
```

Produces:

```
{   
    "avg_occupancy": {
        "1": [0],
        "2": [5, 9, 5],
        "5": [13, 24, 23],
        "7": [56]
    },
    "avg_absences": {
        "1": [0],
        "2": [4, 5, 7],
        "5": [8, 6, 3],
        "7": [8]
    },
    "room_config": {
        "1": ["configa001"],
        "2": ["configa002", "configa003", "configa004"],
        "5": ["configa005", "configa006", "configa008"],
        "7": ["configa007"]
    }
}
```